# GA Regex Match Prefix OR Suffix

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to sort of do a two-in-one regex match for GA keywords

Want to say the following, that either the optional prefix or one (or both) of the optional suffixes must be present to match – along with the 'required middle' string, 'people' in this case

So only these combinations would match:

```
people
happy people
happy people smile
happy people smile often
people smile
people smile often
```

This would not match:

```
happy people smile often in Connecticut
```

Or anything else for that matter

I've never used lookaheads; I'm guessing this might be the solution(?)

Open to other solutions if there are any

Again, I'm using Google Analytics if someone needs to know what regex flavour

**While the above list is useful, I also need to know how to do it so that "people" alone would not match for some queries, but only lines 2-6 in the example**.

So I guess I really need two expressions

Comment: Do you want to capture the entire string or just "people?" You would use lookarounds if only wanted to capture "people," otherwise they are not necessary or even beneficial in this caes.

Comment: Hi, matching "people" as well as the above five matches would also be acceptable; I will add it to the list

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Since `people` is common in all of the variants we'll use it as a definite match (otherwise you end up matching anything and nothing). So `happy` isn't required, we're adding the `?` quantifier to say it's either there or not. Also note that I've included a space inside of the grouping parenthesis. Next `people` is always required, followed by `smile` or `smile often` (with their appropriate spaces). Now if you want metrics from each of these different phrases they would need to be setup as different filters. The code below returns true for all of the words that you've listed. We're using the `^` for the start of line and the `$` for the end of line so we can make sure not to return true for these words inside of a longer phrase.

```
^(happy )?people( smile| smile often)?$
```

Per your additional request, to keep it simple we could make this an `or` statement entirely. I've ordered it this way for speed because REGEX checks from left to right. If a non-existent space is encountered it will move on to the next section of the `or`.

```
^(people smile often|people smile|happy people smile often|happy people smile|happy people)$
```

Comment: Thanks, I would also really appreciate a version where "people" only would not match